# Codlfusion ORM: Can not load SQL after an init of ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion, init

Trying to drop/create table with orm but facing a situation:

When I try to drop/create table I see tables are created but data. I have a sql which contains data but no luck. I have proper definitions for the sql that has to be imported when I drop/create.

```
 this.ormsettings = {autorebuild="false"};
 this.ormsettings.dialect= "oracle10g";
 this.ormsettings.logsql="true";
 this.ormSettings.dbCreate = "dropcreate"; //"dropcreate";
 this.ormsettings.sqlscript="mydata.sql";
 this.ormsettings.eventhandling=true;
 this.ClientManagement="No";
 this.sessionmanagement = true;
 this.sessiontimeout = createTimeSpan(0,2,0,0);
```

When I look at hibernate log files I see following line - which I believe has no sense because  as I googled and I see that this line of log is very common and no one is commenting about it.-

Only clue that I have:

```
</pre>08/16 11:22:00 [jrpp-3] HIBERNATE DEBUG - import file not found: /import.sql
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the mydata.sql file in the same folder as the application.cfc?

Comment: Does it work if you rename your mydata.sql to import.sql?

Comment: @namtax yes mydata.sql is in the same folder of application.cfc
@eapen no it does not work even I rename it to import.sql

Comment: restart CF, see if it still looks for import.sql

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the "autorebuild" setting in the official document : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSED380324-6CBE-47cb-9E5E-26B66ACA9E81.html